# YouTube Videos: Google returns non-existant meta description and different keywords

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search, youtube

I was doing some research for a client and came upon some strange results. I did a search in google videos and it returned 2 very strange results. Why are they strange? The video results in question are results for the cult classic movie, "Re-Animator". If you'll notice, in the visible description that displays on Google, both "Re-Animator" video descriptions contain "Domain Reanimator review" when clearly the review is for a movie. Now, when you go to the actual video page on youtube, there is NOTHING to do with "Domain Reanimator", SOOOOO, my question is:

Why does the Google serps show a completely different and unrelated description for those 2 videos?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Google will occasionally rewrite titles and descriptions to give people a more varied search result. It is true that the video you mention does not mention 'domain' in the title or the description within the source.

However, YouTube as you know brings up similar videos in the sidebar, these may be very relevant, or slightly relevant. Google can rewrite titles and descriptions based on everything found on the page, in this case it is rewriting the description and using content from other videos in the side bar.

*Google in some point of time found these videos in the sidebar:*

- Domain Re-animator Review: Building a PBN on a Budget
- Amok Time Re-Animator Herbert West

These may appear in the title, or description, or both. If the Video is not relevant to what a user is searching for then they are likely to find what they are after in the sidebar, so its not a major issue.

This is not Google misbehaving and in fact is intended by Google. Rewriting happens more often than you must likely realise, its not an issue and actually improves the user experience.

Comment: Of course, given that YouTube is actually owned and operated by Google, you'd think they could be a little smarter about integrating it. But I guess, with a company as big and multi-branched as Google, the left tentacle no longer always knows what the right tentacle is doing. (For that matter, even for sites *not* owned by Google, you'd think the search folks could program their engine to ignore or at least significantly de-weight irrelevant random sidebar text. Maybe not for *every* site, but a site as big as YouTube could surely merit a bit of extra human attention and analysis.)

Comment: Your notice better results in videos with higher volume of views because YouTube has more chance to learn from others what is relevant and what is not. This will happen on low volume and uncompetitive keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It's just how the poster worded the title and description and basically chose a custom thumbnail.

Comment: If you'll look at the video publish date, it's 12/03/2012. That's 3 years before Domain ReAnimator even came out.